# Visual Studio tries to locate AutoMapper's PrimitiveExtensions.cs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, automapper

I have a model that I'm mapping to DTO. All the mapping should be set up correctly. I'm using:

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

I retrieve the model from the db. Its properties, including its child entities are correct and they are exactly what is found in the tables.

However, when I try to map it to DTO:

```
var entity = myService.Get(id)
var dto = Mapper.Map<myDTO>(entity);
```

Visual Studio shows the Open File dialog and tries to open the file `PrimitiveExtensions.cs`. I can't stop the app, and I need to end Visual Studio from the Task Manager.

This problem occurs for only one particular model (and it's child entities). Does it occur because the mapping is not set up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your VS tries to open the source file because it breaks on a first chance exception. Usually you should be able to cancel the file open dialog and then analyze the call stack or simply continue running the code.

You can disable breaking on first chance exception in the Debug -> Exceptions dialog.

In case it isn't only a first chance exception but an unhandled one you can tell VS to not try to open the library code by enabling "Enable just my code" in Tools - Options - Debugging.

Comment: I didn't find it in the list

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Just uncheck the "Thrown" column of all exceptions.

Comment: Did that. It still shows the Open File dialog, and I can only kill the VS process from Task Manager.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I've updated my answer. Try to enable "Enable just my code" in VS options.